# xcopy not copying directories. unsure why

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo on
cls
set "root"="%CD%"
cd bin\cemu*
xcopy /q .\mlc01\* "%root%\temp\mlc01\" /e /i /y
xcopy /q .\hfiomlc01\* "%root%\temp\hfiomlc01\" /e /i /y
cd ..
rmdir /s /q cemu_1.7.3d
rmdir /s /q cemu_1.7.4d
cd ..
cd bin\cemu*
xcopy /q "%root%\temp\" .\mlc01\* /e /i /y
xcopy /q "%root%\temp\"  .\hfiomlc01\* /e /i /y
cd "%root%"
pause
```

everything works fine with changing directories and everything but xcopy isn't copying directories or anything (I used this same command in my other project to and it works fine but here it wont)
I tried /s /t /e and all that stuff and I still cant get it going

Comment: You appear to be using an asterisk for your `CD` command, however you are removing two specific directories whose name begins with the same string. Are you expecting the `CD` command to change to all directories beginning with that string or just one?

Comment: To clarify the situation for us as well as for you I suggest you use the tree.exe utility and show the relevant parts of the tree.

Comment: Try one of the xcopy commands from the command line (in the correct directory). Does it work there or not? Does anything interesting get shown if you take out the `/q` options?

Comment: /q just makes it not show output. .\bla\bla\* works fine with moving only if theres files /e /I /y is supposed to include subdirectories and cd .\bin\cemu* changes to the first directory with the name (which would be the oldest in this case) again: directory changing works fine. I cant seem to xcopy the directories out.

Comment: btw I know the last two are formatted wrong. I was just testing something to see if it produced some input to help. the first to are what I'm looking for.

Comment: I make these in my spare time as a hobby and they are not meant to be taken as a consumer product ^^" and if I did that for every batch command id have lines that are infinitely long. and the program worked before and I found out what it was. thank you for your *kind* *understanding* *patient* response

Comment: also it does output the correct path so its not an issue with variables. I know how to debug a program. it was an issue with the quotes. also feel free to comment on my other  work understanding human https://github.com/MarioMasta64/EverythingPortable/releases/latest/ also yes I know my code is messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
set "root"="%CD%"
```

to:

```
set "root=%CD%"
```

Due to the quirks that exist in `cmd.exe`'s quoting (`cmd.exe` has so many quirks) the first variation doesn't do what you want it it to do - it creates an environment variable named `root"` (yes, the environment variable name has a trailing double-quote character).

Comment: cmd is weird @~@ explains why I didn't have the problem when I used set root=%CD% (people had pathing problems because of this tho) ill try this and see how it works (when I become unlazy)

Comment: thank you for this. it works perfectly now ^~^ and yea it was when I tried to fix issues with people who like to have spaces in their folders that this issue arrised. ill be updating all my other batch files with this format soon (strangely tho if "bla"=="bla" do blah works fine tho. cmd is truly weird)

Comment: I was basically putting quotes around things as to make peoples paths not complain and I made this problem. you fixed 2 of my projects with this helpfulness ^~^ CemuPortableLauncher and SteamPortableLauncher